Trying to test out opencv example from matlab and get error opencv2/opencv.hpp not found
I followed the directions from the Matlab video (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47953-computer-vision-toolbox-interface-for-opencv-in-matlab).
I downloaded the apps Computer Vision Toolbox, Image Processing Toolbox, and Computer Vision Toolbox Interface for OpenCV in Matlab.
When I run this code: mexOpenCV matchTemplateOCV.cpp
I get the error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
I didn't change anything and I'm following their instructions from the README.txt file.
I also can't find an opencv2 folder or opencv.hpp file, but I'm using exactly what they gave me when I downloaded the apps.
Can someone explain why I get this error and how to fix it?

You probably need to download OpenCV as well. Both the library and the header files.
